# Why has the top half of my Acer Garnet died off

Tags: diagnosis, shrubs

The shrub is approx. 14 years old and has been planted in the garden for about the past 6 years. I have mulched it twice in that time. What have I done wrong? Any advice would be good.

Comment: Welcome hsh! Would you please post a picture of your shrub? It's hard to get the best answers if we can't see it. Also, where do you live? By dying off do you mean getting brown, or leaves are dropping, or what kind of damage are you seeing? Has it been going on a long time? Have you done anything different? We ask for a lot of details because that's the only way for us to give you the best advice. Since you're new here, I invite you to check out our [help]. [Ask] is a good place to start. I hope you give us more information so we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Acers are prone to dieback, and if yours has not leafed out at the top this year, that's likely what the trouble is. Sometimes the plant recovers, or just carries on growing lower down after you remove the dead upper growth, but other times the dieback advances and the whole plant dies.

There are various causes for dieback, but the commonest one in Acer palmatum is due to verticillium wilt, to which these plants are highly susceptible. It's most commonly a soil borne infection, and you won't have caused it, it can be wind borne. More information re verticillium wilt here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=255.

Comment: Thankyou, I live in West Sussex, garden faces southwest, but acer is placed in a position where there's little wind. But sun.  Die off means that the top half is just not producing red leaves. It doesn't look dead but just not growing. Not brown and it has only happened this year. No production of leafing. Do I cut off the "dead"  bits or just leave it alone?

Comment: Well you can wait another week or so, but if nothing at all is growing on that part by 1st May, cut out the dead wood. Don't go too far past the dead wood - cutting live wood at this time of year on Acers will cause a lot of bleeding. Unfortunately, dieback is pretty common here (in the UK).